# Creating an account number session variable upon login in dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver CS6, PHP and MYSQL. I have my registration/login page built in order for the user to choose a username/password. The trouble is, across my many database tables, I'm using an account ID# to connect them all. When a user logs in, the login page creates a session for MM_Username, but I also need it to pull the specific account number(s) associated for that username (user may have more than one account). I can't figure out how to create a session variable for the available account numbers associated with the specific username. ???

```
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "partners/index.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "ad-login-help.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_Establishments, $Establishments);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT username, password FROM advertisers            WHERE username=%s AND password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"),     GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $Establishments) or     die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
 $loginStrGroup = "";

if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
//declare two session variables and assign them
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;


if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
}
header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. I've looked everywhere and can't suss this one out. :/